# how to customize android default classes(datepicker,numpicker,etc)

Tags: java, android, class, datepicker

I want to make a custom date-picker for android and I need to change something in `datepicker.class` file in `android.widget package`. In fact, I want to change the year and month for solar **hijri**  calendar.

I found source code of `datepicker.java` in http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java.shtml  - but I don't know how to change and replace it with default android class. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean applying Jalali calendar to `DatePicker`? You should consider the difference between applying a specific calendar to `DatePicker` and modifying its GUI. I think you need to redesign the GUI.

Comment: yes i want to apply jalali calendar to datepicker. as i did not know how to  do it i think that it may be done by changing in datepicker class. in other hand it would be amazing to know how to replace a default android class with my custom one.so i will be thankful if help me.

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way to do this is to copy the source code for the datepicker class, and rename/modify it as your own class for the hijri calendar.  You could then import or extend this new class to work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this custom view which implement jalali date on it 
https://github.com/alibehzadian/PersianDatePicker
you could just copy the classes ,layout , values on it and paste them in your project and now you have datepicker for jalali date jsut follow the usage instructions on the provided link